# Why did sage bringi only worship shiva

Tags: shiva, shakti

[Why did sage bringi only worship only shiva and not shakti](http://www.jyotirlinga.com/64---stories-of-lord-shiva.html)
What happened with rishi bringi after shakti took shakti(power ) from sage bringi's body.
In durga chalisa there is a line

> *Nishidin dhyan dharo shekar ko*
>
> *kahu kaal nhi sumiro tumko*
>
> *shakti roop ko maran na payo*
>
> *shakti gayi tab man pachitayo*
>
> *sharnagat Hui Kirti bakhani*
>
> *Jay Jay Jay jagdamb bhavani*
>
> *Bhai prasann aadi jagdamba*
>
> *dai shakti nahi kin vilamba*

In this who is that person "kaal" is it same rishi bringi?